# Concerns: Using Social Media Tokens in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, security, social-networking

I want to use social-feed jquery widget ( https://github.com/pavelk2/social-feed ) on my website. 
I've been doing some tests and it works fine. However, for the plugin to work, for facebook for example, i have to set my app id and my secret app id (format: appid|secretid). 
For instagram to work, i have to set the clientid and an accesstoken for it to pull images from my account. 
For twitter I can set the app to read only so this should be fine.

My question is, how safe is that? Putting an access token and secret apl ids on the client side.  What are the consequences of such steps that i should be worried about (if any)?  And is their a way to overcome such issues?

Thank you.

Comment: If it's a secret, displaying it on the clientside is probably not a very good idea.

Comment: "Not a very good idea" is the reason I am asking the question. But the question is what are the consequences? What are possible actions that can be done with such information. And that would mean that all sites having this plugin are at risk?

Comment: Well, the **first** thing in Facebooks documentation is *"Never include your App Secret in client-side or decompilable code."*, so it seems weird that a plugin would require you to do that. If someone has both the secret and the ID they can use Facebook on behalf of your app, which can be bad.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Using on behalf of the app would be a minimal concern in this case as the app is just for this purpose. I wont need permissions. Yet my major concern is with instagram. Can they post or do changes in the account using the access token?